# Thread-safe Map in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I understand the overall concepts of multi-threading and synchronization but am new to writing thread-safe code. I currently have the following code snippet:

```
synchronized(compiledStylesheets) {
    if(compiledStylesheets.containsKey(xslt)) {
        exec = compiledStylesheets.get(xslt);
    } else {
        exec = compile(s, imports);
        compiledStylesheets.put(xslt, exec);
    }
}
```

where `compiledStylesheets` is a `HashMap` (private, final). I have a few questions.

The compile method can take a few hundred milliseconds to return. This seems like a long time to have the object locked, but I don't see an alternative. Also, it is unnecessary to use Collections.synchronizedMap in addition to the `synchronized` block, correct? This is the only code that hits this object other than initialization/instantiation.

Alternatively, I know of the existence of a `ConcurrentHashMap` but I don't know if that's overkill. The `putIfAbsent()` method will not be usable in this instance because it doesn't allow me to skip the `compile()` method call. I also don't know if it will solve the "modified after `containsKey()` but before `put()`" problem, or if that's even really a concern in this case.

Edit: Spelling

Comment: What about having the exec statement instead add the key to a queue, and have some process execute the queue every so often?  In this way it is guaranteed to be "safe" and not add the same key mutliple times

Comment: What is xlst? You can lock on that. You can use a "lock on keys" cache approach. Alternatively use a `ConcurrentHashMap`.

Comment: @MarshallTigerus I assume the op needs to `return exec` from that method.

Comment: @assylias insufficient information to assume that, though.

Comment: For tasks of this nature, I highly recommend [Guava caching support.](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained)

Comment: Agreed with @erickson. This is clearly beyond simple locking.

Comment: @assylias - Isn't this a variant of your very nice  [Multiton](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18149547/823393)?

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon that would work!

Comment: @erickson Was not aware of those, definitely reading up now.

Comment: @erickson Wish I could accept your comment as my answer, I've changed my code to use a `com.google.common.cache.Cache`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For tasks of this nature, I highly recommend [Guava caching support.](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained)

If you can't use that library, here is a compact implementation of a [Multiton.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiton_pattern) Use of the `FutureTask` was a tip from [assylias, here,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11126866/thread-safe-multitons-in-java/18149547#18149547) via [OldCurmudgeon.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23203625/3474)

```
public abstract class Cache<K, V>
{

  private final ConcurrentMap<K, Future<V>> cache = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

  public final V get(K key)
    throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException
  {
    Future<V> ref = cache.get(key);
    if (ref == null) {
      FutureTask<V> task = new FutureTask<>(new Factory(key));
      ref = cache.putIfAbsent(key, task);
      if (ref == null) {
        task.run();
        ref = task;
      }
    }
    return ref.get();
  }

  protected abstract V create(K key)
    throws Exception;

  private final class Factory
    implements Callable<V>
  {

    private final K key;

    Factory(K key)
    {
      this.key = key;
    }

    @Override
    public V call()
      throws Exception
    {
      return create(key);
    }

  }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for a [Multiton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiton_pattern).

There's a very good Java one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11126866/thread-safe-multitons-in-java/18149547#18149547) that @assylas posted some time ago.

Comment: The linked answer uses ConcurrentHashMap in two different ways, depending on whether JDK8 is being used.  Both appear very clean, high-performing, and race-condition-free.

Comment: Yes, this is the solution I came up with, but I used a `CountDownLatch` instead of a `FutureTask`. Something like this is the way to go.

Comment: @erickson - I like the elegance of the `FutureTask`.

Comment: Yes, `FutureTask` is good, I had just forgotten that they did what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can loosen the lock at the risk of an occasional doubly  compiled stylesheet in race condition.

```
Object y;

// lock here if needed
y = map.get(x);
if(y == null) {
    y = compileNewY();

    // lock here if needed
    map.put(x, y); // this may happen twice, if put is t.s. one will be ignored
    y = map.get(x); // essential because other thread's y may have been put
}
```

This requires `get` and `put` to be atomic, which is true in the case of `ConcurrentHashMap` and you can achieve by wrapping individual calls to `get` and `put` with a lock in your class. (As I tried to explain with "lock here if needed" comments - the point being you only need to wrap individual calls, not have one big lock).

This is a standard thread safe pattern to use even with `ConcurrentHashMap` (and putIfAbsent) to minimize the cost of compiling twice. It still needs to be acceptable to compile twice sometimes, but it should be okay even if expensive.

By the way, you can solve that problem. Usually the above pattern isn't used with a heavy function like `compileNewY` but a lightweight constructor `new Y()`. e.g. do this:

```
class PrecompiledY {
    public volatile Y y;
    private final AtomicBoolean compiled = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    public void compile() {
        if(!compiled.getAndSet(true)) {
            y = compile();
        }
    }
}
// ...
ConcurrentMap<X, PrecompiledY> myMap; // alternatively use proper locking

py = map.get(x);
if(py == null) {
    py = new PrecompiledY(); // much cheaper than compiling

    map.put(x, y); // this may happen twice, if put is t.s. one will be ignored
    y = map.get(x); // essential because other thread's y may have been put
    y.compile(); // object that didn't get inserted never gets compiled
}
```

Also:

> Alternatively, I know of the existence of a ConcurrentHashMap but I don't know if that's overkill.

Given that your code is heavily locking, ConcurrentHashMap is almost certainly far faster, so not overkill. (And much more likely to be bug-free. Concurrency bugs are *not* fun to fix.)

Comment: I am unable to understand parts of this. Can you please clarify "lock here if needed" comments? When are locks needed? Also, does this code not allow compile by multiple threads? That would be resource-waste, no?

Comment: @MiserableVariable As long as `get` and `put` are threadsafe, this algorithm is threadsafe. It does not need any locking across accesses to `map`.

Comment: @MiserableVariable see my edit for how to solve the problem of wasting a compile.

Comment: This will break if the map is not a `ConcurrentMap` (or something that uses memory barriers in a similar way).

Comment: @erickson I tried to explain poorly in the answer and in the comments that the algo only assumes `put` and `get` are atomic, which can be achieved by wrapping them in locks or using a common `ConcurrentMap` implementation. Is there another problem?

Comment: I am talking about the second example. It doesn't explain that `map` must be a `ConcurrentMap`.

Answer (score 1):

**Please see Erickson's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23202632/thread-safe-map-in-java/23202696?noredirect=1#comment35491735_23202696) below. Using double-checked locking with Hashmaps is not very smart**

> The compile method can take a few hundred milliseconds to return. This seems like a long time to have the object locked, but I don't see an alternative.

You can use double-checked locking, and note that you don't need any lock before `get` since you never remove anything from the map.

```
if(compiledStylesheets.containsKey(xslt)) {
    exec = compiledStylesheets.get(xslt);
} else {
    synchronized(compiledStylesheets) {
        if(compiledStylesheets.containsKey(xslt)) {
            // another thread might have created it while
            // this thread was waiting for lock
            exec = compiledStylesheets.get(xslt);
        } else {
            exec = compile(s, imports);
            compiledStylesheets.put(xslt, exec);
        }
    }
}
```

}

> Also, it is unnecessary to use Collections.synchronizedMap in addition to the synchronized block, correct?

Correct

> This is the only code that hits this object other than initialization/instantiation.

Comment: I was hesitant to call containsKey twice but I suppose it's pretty fast on a HashMap...

Comment: This is bad. You can't extend the thread-safe double-checked locking idiom to a `HashMap`. Simply invoking `get()` on a `HashMap` that might be modified asynchronously can cause bugs when modifications due to rehashing become visible non-atomically or out of order.

Comment: It is probably better to call it twice than to lock it; this is a write-rarely,read-frequently scenario.

Comment: @erickson I had not considered rehashing. Now I am (again) wondering about the value of double-checked locking, having myself used it mostly for managing such maps. Do you know if the unlocked `get` can throw exception or return wrong results? Since the second `get` is guarded, I am wondering if it is safe (even if ugly) to ignore the error in the first call.

Comment: Whether the unguarded `get()` can throw exceptions is implementation-specific, and the conditions that lead to problems have varied over the years. In some versions, it was reported that an infinite loop could occur, so you wouldn't even get an exception to ignore. There are better solutions that are efficient and guaranteed to be correct by the Java memory model.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the code as you posted it is `race-condition`-free because `containsKey()` result will never change while `compile()` method is running.

`Collections.synchronizedMap()` is useless for your case as stated above because it wraps all map methods into a `synchronized` block using either `this` as a mutex or another object you provided (for two-argument version).

IMO using `ConcurrentHashMap` is also not an option because it stripes locks based on key `hashCode()` result; its concurrent iterators is also useless here.

If you really want `compile()` out of `synchronized` block, you may pre-calculate if before checking `containsKey()`. This may draw the overall performance back, but may be better than calling it in `synchronized` block. To make a decision, personally I would consider how often key "miss" is happening and so, which option is preferrable - keep the lock for longer times or calculate your stuff always.